# WWW::Mechanize enter input that is not part of a form

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm working on a web crawling project and I have trouble targeting inputs that are not part of a form. Something like this:

```
<div>
    Book name: <input type="text" name="book" /><br />
    Student: <input type="text" name="student" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Ajax call:

```
$("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
    type: "POST",
    url: "borrow.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
            book: $("input[name='book']").val(),
            student: $("input[name='student']").val()
          }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { ...  }
});
```

I'm just wondering if I can use Mechanize to enter data and submit the so called form.

I tried using post() to POST data straight, but the success() function handles too many instructions, so I would like to click on the submit button instead.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize doesn't have a JavaScript engine. Searching for WWW::Mechanize JavaScript should find solutions.

Comment: What you want is sending a `POST` request with the following body: `{"book": <yourval>, "student": <yourval>}` to the url `borrow.php`. Since `WWW::Mechanize` is a `LWP::UserAgent` you should be able to use its `post` method to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem today by doing the following:

```
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();

# Or however else you get your form data to submit
my $field1 = shift($m->find_all_inputs(name => 'field1'))->value;
my $field2 = shift($m->find_all_inputs(name => 'field2'))->value;

$m->post('http://somesite.com/expectsPost.cgi',
{ field1 => $field1,
  field2 => $field2,
  action => 'DoSomethingCool' });

my $result = $m->content;
```

Hope this helps!